# Enable dynamic debug for multiple files at boot

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

How to enable dynamic debugging (`pr_debug`) at boot for multiple files by supplying a command line argument to the linux kernel?

I tried to provide the following as an argument -

`dyndbg='file drivers/<filename1> +p file drivers/<filename2> +p file drivers/<filename3> +p'`

However the dynamic debugging was not enabled.

Is my syntax correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Separate control commands with semicolons.

```
dyndbg='file drivers/<filename1> +p; file drivers/<filename2> +p; file drivers/<filename3> +p'
```

Answer (score 2):

1. First, check if you have enabled `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG=y` this in the `.config` file
2. Test if this works properly when the kernel is booted.

   ```
   echo -n 'module module_name +p' > /debugfs/dynamic_debug/control
   ```
3. Make sure the QUERY is in correct format (where the path to the module/folder is correct) when specified with `dyndbg=QUERY`

For built-in module use `dyndbg='module module_name +p'`

For loadable module use `module_name.dyndbg=<query>` ex: `xhci_hcd.dyndbg=+p`

You can add it to your Linux default command line by writing the `/etc/default/grub` file as follows:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="xhci_hcd.dyndbg=+p"
```

[Refer link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/dynamic-debug-howto.txt):

> Debug messages during Boot Process
>
> To activate debug messages for core code and built-in modules during
>   the boot process, even before userspace and debugfs exists, use
>   dyndbg="QUERY", module.dyndbg="QUERY", or ddebug_query="QUERY"
>   (ddebug_query is obsoleted by dyndbg, and deprecated).  QUERY follows
>   the syntax described above, but must not exceed 1023 characters.  Your
>   bootloader may impose lower limits.
>
> These dyndbg params are processed just after the ddebug tables are
>   processed, as part of the arch_initcall.  Thus you can enable debug
>   messages in all code run after this arch_initcall via this boot
>   parameter.

Comment: I already checked for step1 and step2 and it is just fine. Maybe I am not clear from my question. I wanted to ask that for multiple files is my QUERY correct or not. How do I verify it?

Comment: I have not tried with multiple files, but can you try `dyndbg='file module_name/path/to/files/* +p` if this works

Comment: I don't want to add all files, because there are lot of files in the directory.

Comment: Uboot:    setenv bootargs dyndbg=\"file drivers/of/* +p\; file arch/arm/mm/init.c +p\"

Comment: Doesn't address multiple specific file requirement.