# Enable dynamic debug at boot

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel

This question might be similar to [Enable dynamic debug for multiple files at boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744402/enable-dynamic-debug-for-multiple-files-at-boot)

But when I add the query as "set bootargs '`ddebug_query=\"file drivers/<filename1> +p\"', ddebug_setup_query()` function in `lib/dynamic_debug.c` takes the query as only "file", given file name and option is left out.

**Kernel command line looks like**

```
console=ttyMSM0,115200n8 ddebug_query=file drivers/clk/clk.c +p
```

It seems like, the query is parsed until the space.

Can somebody help out, how can I enable this feature in boot? or is there any issue with the syntax?

Comment: I think ddebug_query is obsoleted by dyndbg, and deprecated. In your case you can try with below syntax console=ttyMSM0,115200n8 ddebug_query="file drivers/clk/clk.c +p".

Comment: Thanks for your comment @vinodmaverick. I set the bootargs as you mentioned in your comments. However, in kernel command line, the quotes are removed and it looks like below:

`ddebug_query=file drivers/clk/clk.c +p`

I suspect the qoutes removal is the issue here. Is that something bootloader has some role in eliminating the qoutes? or something else I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting the bootargs as `dyndbg=\\"file drivers/clk/clk.c +p\\"`, proper query has been sent through kernel command line and it worked as expected.